# Anomaly in test data-set for carrying out multivariate regression in python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a dataset (train, test and result) which consists of 32 Independent Variables and 5 Dependent Variables. To get a grasp of the data, I am trying to build a simple linear regression model on it and test its performance.

But all the rows of dependent variables in the test data set are filled with "?".

`Salary DOJ DOL Designation JobCity
  ?     ?    ?      ?         ?
  ?     ?    ?      ?         ?
  ?     ?    ?      ?         ?
  ?     ?    ?      ?         ?
  ?     ?    ?      ?         ?
  ?     ?    ?      ?         ?`

Out of these 5 dependent variables, I am trying to predict the Salary (with the help of 32 independent variables).

When I implement this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def get_data(file_name):
    train = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Shubhanshu/Desktop/train.xlsx")
    X_train = train.drop(['ID', 'Salary'], axis=1)
    #Keeping only numeric data
    X_train = X_train._get_numeric_data()
    y_train = train.Salary
    return y_train, X_train
Y, X = get_data("C:/Users/Shubhanshu/Desktop/train.xlsx")

clf = LinearRegression()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

def get_test_data(file_name):
    test = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Shubhanshu/Desktop/test.xlsx")
    X_test = test.drop(['ID', 'Salary'], axis=1)
    #Keeping only numeric data
    X_test = X_test._get_numeric_data()
    y_test = test.Salary
    return X_test, y_test

X1, Y1 = get_test_data("C:/Users/Shubhanshu/Desktop/test.xlsx")
r_sqr = clf.score(X1, Y1)
y_pred = clf.predict(X1)
```

I get the error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ?`

After searching thoroughly on the material available and the tutorials, I guess I can replace all the '?' with let's say a scalar value such as 0. But, won't it effect the model then (I am sorry, but this is more of a first hands-on project with ML and a proper dataset, so please forgive my ignorance in the matter)? Or else, how should I proceed ahead in such a case?

P.S: I tried this:

```
test = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Shubhanshu/Desktop/test.xlsx")
X_test = test.drop(['ID', 'Salary'], axis=1)
#Keeping only numeric data

#test.dtypes
test.Salary = test.Salary.fillna('missing')
test.DOJ = test.DOJ.fillna('missing')
test.DOL = test.DOL.fillna('missing')
test.Designation = test.Designation.fillna('missing')
test.JobCity = test.JobCity.fillna('missing')
#test = test.Salary.fillna('missing')
y_test = test.Salary
#test.info
X_test.DOJ = test.DOJ.fillna('missing')
X_test.DOL = test.DOL.fillna('missing')
X_test.Designation = test.Designation.fillna('missing')
X_test.JobCity = test.JobCity.fillna('missing')
X_test = X_test._get_numeric_data()
#X_test
X_test = X_test.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print mse
```

But obviously, since y_test has all "missing" written in each of its cell, mse or mae won't return anything meaningful. This is what I got in return:

```
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-b384f3be69ab> in <module>()
----> 1 mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
      2 mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
      3 print mse

F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\regression.pyc in mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    137 
    138     """
--> 139     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    140     return np.average(np.abs(y_pred - y_true).mean(axis=1),
    141                       weights=sample_weight)

F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\regression.pyc in _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     56     """
     57     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
---> 58     y_true = check_array(y_true, ensure_2d=False)
     59     y_pred = check_array(y_pred, ensure_2d=False)
     60 

F:\PythonIDE\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features)
    342             else:
    343                 dtype = None
--> 344         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    345         # make sure we actually converted to numeric:
    346         if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":

ValueError: could not convert string to float: missing
```

I would be really grateful for any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

In future could you please include the full traceback in your question rather than just the last line? I suspect that the problem is here:

```
r_sqr = clf.score(X1, Y1)
```

Here, `Y1` represents the dependent variables for the test dataset, which just consist of "`?`" nonsense values.

I think there is a conceptual misunderstanding here - what you're doing just doesn't make sense. There's no way you could possibly compute a score for the test dataset, since you don't know the true values of the dependent variables.

Comment: I have added the traceback. Also, even I feel that having such non-sense values in the test data doesn't make sense. But this is what is there in the "test" dataset provided (separately with training data).

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can say - computing a mean squared error score without having real values for the dependent variable is impossible (although `clf.predict(X1)` should work fine).